# Excel VBA Looping using criteria and 2 sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to do something that I am really not sure how to do.

I have 2 spread sheets sheet1 and sheet2

On sheet 1 I have
Column A a list of numbers (SalespersonsID)
Column B the sum of column B on sheet 2

```
SalespersonID | Total sales
--------------+------------
            1 | 
            2 |
```

on sheet 2 I have
Column A has the salespersonsID
Column B has how many widgets were sold by the sales person in that transaction
Column C has TypeofWidget
Column D has Location

```
SalespersonID | Units sold | Type | Location
--------------+------------+------+-----------
            1 |          1 | Foo  | London
            1 |          2 | Bar  | London
            2 |          4 | Foo  | Berlin
            1 |          1 | Bar  | Madrid
```

I dont know  how to do this but I need to insert the total of number of widgets sold by a salesman using Sheet2's columns C and D and also sheet 1's sales ID as criteria and insert it into Sheet1 column B?

```
SalespersonID | Total sales
--------------+------------
            1 |           4
            2 |           4
```

I can do it in a cell using the SumIFS function but I have over 500 rows to go through on 5 sheets total.

Comment: I *think* I've interpreted the description correctly to show the sample data. @user1497083 please edit the question again if something is wrong.

Comment: Seems like a good use case for a pivot table

Comment: You are looking for the *Pivot Table* feature in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

this is a vba sub that do the required job, just put it in vba and run :

```
sub totalSales()
  Dim i As Integer 'used to loop on sheet1
  Dim j As Integer 'used to loop on sheet2
  Dim spID As Integer 'the SalepersonID in Sheets1
  Dim spID2 As Integer 'the SalepersonID in Sheets2
  Dim rows1 as Integer 'rows count in sheet1
  Dim rows2 as Integer 'rows count in sheet2
  Dim total as Integer 'to count sales per person

  'getting rows count
  rows1=Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'rows count in sheet1
  rows2=Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'rows count in sheet2

    For i = 1 To rows1 
        spID =  Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value) 'the salepersonID
        total=0 'initializing counter
        for j= 1 to rows2
            spID2 =  Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, "A").Value 
            If (UserID=UserID2) Then
                total = total + Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, "B").Value
            End If
        next j
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(i, "B").Value = total ' Storing the total in sheet1
    next i

End Sub
```